# Facebook message notification

Tags: notifications, facebook

Is there away to make my phone stop beeping when I get a Facebook message if I'm already on Facebook on a different computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there away to make my phone stop beeping when I get a Facebook message *if I'm already on Facebook on a different computer?*

Emphasis mine. No, there is currently no way for the Facebook app to only send you messages when the phone is the only device connected. The only option you have is shutting of certain kinds of notifications completely.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if you reply on a PC to the person who is sending you the messages, the notifications will be silent on your phone. Other than that, it doesn't seem to be currently possible.